# How to fix the permission denied error? (happens in any IDE)

Tags: python

I am trying to run a python file. But i got this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "modeltraining.py", line 29, in <module>
    sr,audio = read(source + path)
  File "C:\Users\RAAM COMPUTERS\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\io\wavfile.py", line 233, in read
    fid = open(filename, 'rb')
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'development_set/'
```

Answer (score 3):

Run Spyder as administrator
Right click --> run as administrator

Or may be you can change the permissions of the directory you want to save to so that all users have read and write permissions.

Comment: I am new to spyder. How to run as administrator?

Comment: Just go to logo of spyder if standalone , right click and run as administrator , or if anaconda then run anaconda as administrator and then run Spyder.

Comment: Could you change the permission of folder, and try

Comment: This has not solved the issue in my case. I have a Python script on an external card, and my previous laptop could handle this, while my new computer does not accept it, still outputs the same permission error.

Answer (score 1):

After some time relaunching Anaconda and Spyder, I got an alert from Avast antivirus about protecting me from a malicious file, the one I was trying to create.

After allowing it, the "[Errno 13] Permission denied" error disappeared.

In my case, it seem the cause of the problem was Avast locking the directory.

numpy.save(array, path) worked fine, but PIL.Image().save(path) was blocked.

Answer (score 0):

I am completely late to the party, but here is a tip for someone who tried everything and it didn't work.
In Spyder go to `python->PYTHONPATH manager` and add path to the folder with your data there.
Worked for me

Comment: This has not solved the issue in my case. I have a Python script on an external card, and my previous laptop could handle this, while my new computer does not accept it, still outputs the same permission error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the permission error when accessing a file on an external card. I guess the error has nothing to do with anaconda, that is just accidentally in the traceback.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3343, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-2-219c041de52a>", line 105, in <module>
    bs = open(filename, 'rb').read()
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'D:\\[MYFILEPATH]\\test.bson'
```

I have checked this error in Spyder and PyCharm, it seems to be independent from the IDE. As the (Windows) solutions here (run as admin, add pythonpath) could not help me, my workaround was to copy the directory to my local disk and work from there.

Later I realised that it is obviously just the one file that is accessed ant that throws the permission that needs to be copied to your local disk, while you can use all your codework on externally.

Example:

Error. Get the permission error by accessing external drive "D:\":

```
filename = "D:\\test.bson"
# This throws the permission error
bs = open(filename, 'rb').read()
```

Solution. Avoid the permission error by accessing local drive "C:\":

```
filename = "C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\test.bson"
# This throws no permission error
bs = open(filename, 'rb').read()
```

The whole code can now be saved on external "D:\test.py".

It might be the Windows Defender Firewall which was also mentioned when I installed PyCharm (and needed some automatic configurations which also did not solve the issue, but could be linked with it). It is clearly a problem of access rights, the firewall as the cause is quite plausible. Perhaps someone else finds out more about this.